# Old Passport Stapled with back cover of my new passport, will the holes be a problem?

Tags: indian-citizens, passports

My old passport and new passport were stapled together while  returning  from the visa embassy. After I managed to remove the staples from my Passport. Now I can see staple holes on the back cover of my new passport. Would it be a problem for my travel? Should I apply for a new passport?

Comment: A picture of the back cover showing the staple holes would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, No tears, it’s just the staple holes.

Answer (score 6):

**No, it's not a problem.**  Staple holes, stickers etc on the back of your passport are very common and are ignored by immigration officials, because the back cover holds no useful information and has no use other than protection.

Staple holes on the *front* cover of your passport could be a problem if they affect the biometric data on the other side (name, birth date, etc), but this doesn't sound like it's the case here.

Comment: Note that many passports (such as US passports, but almost definately others) include the NFC electronics in the back cover, but hopefullyl the antenna was left undamaged.

Comment: Mine is Indian passport, I can see barcode wid passport number on back cover which is undamaged. But not sure whether it has got NFC electronics. How to  check this out on passport? Please advise

Comment: @ShahlHamid I'm not familiar with Indian passports, but the page with the chip will be much thicker than the others, and it's usually (not always) either inside the front cover or in the middle.  If the page can easily be stapled, it's unlikely to contain a chip.